# HTTP Header to Forbid Iframe On Page

Tags: http, iframe, browser, http-headers

There is the Header X-Frame-Options, which is served by the webserver when you want to forbid (or limit) other sites from embedding your page into theirs, using an iframe.

But, is there a Header which tells the browser: "Don't allow any Iframe to be loaded on this page"?

There are, of course, headers which tell the browser which scripts, from which domain, is it allowed to execute, but I want something more generic: "don't allow any iframe, or only iframes from certain origins, to be loaded on this page".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Content-Security-Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CSP) (CSP) can be used to restrict content on pages, including iframes. Specifically, the [`frame-src` directive](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/frame-src). If you set the following HTTP header, no iframes will be allowed on your page.

`Content-Security-Policy: frame-src 'none'`

If you want to only allow iframes from specific origins you could do the following to allow iframes from example.com, and all subdomains:

`Content-Security-Policy: frame-src http://*.example.com`

You can also set the CSP policy via meta tag.